# Firefox  WebDriver does not find the element of the page

Tags: firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I would like to use WebDriver (Firefox) to test my webpage, but I always get this message:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id='something_spicy']"}
```

But, the really strange thing is that if I copy the element locator `"//li[@id='something_spicy']"` and paste it into Firefinder then it works. Basically, I ran out of thoughts about what could be the root cause.

I use C# and here is the code:

```
movedElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id='" + originalOrderOfSportContainers[1] + "']"));
```

Did I do something wrong? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

1. provide a snippet of the html code of your page.
2. There is a chance that element is not there immediately after the page is loaded,
   but appears a bit later as a result of some javascript function execution.
   If this is the case, use [explicit wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits) to wait for element to appear before using it.